# Managing a daily shopping list, 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
def cart():
    while True:
        s = input('Add new item to shopping list: ')
        if s != '0':
            cart.append(s)
        else:
            print('Items on your shopping list are:')
            print(', '.join(cart))
            break
cart = []
cart()
```

This is my code and when I try to run it gives:

***Error***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "__tester__.python3", line 17, in <module>

   cart()

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: You are using `cart` as both as the name of a list and the name of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `cart` as a function, then redifined it as an empty list.  Python will only hold one version of `cart` in memory at a time.  You can give your function a different name and that should fix your problem.

```py
def run_cart():
    while True:
        s = input('Add new item to shopping list: ')
        if s != '0':
            cart.append(s)
        else:
            print('Items on your shopping list are:')
            print(', '.join(cart))
            break
cart = []
run_cart()
```

Comment: "Python will only hold one version of cart in memory at a time"-- not necessarily, this depends on the implementation details of python's garbage collection (of course shadowing `cart` is still the issue)

Answer (score 0):

you just declared `cart` as a `list`, and then you call it.

change your function name from `cart` to `process_input` or anything equal, and just call `process_input()`

```
def process_input():
    while True:
        s = input('Add new item to shopping list: ')
        if s != '0':
            cart.append(s)
        else:
            print('Items on your shopping list are:')
            print(', '.join(cart))
            break
cart = []
process_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a namespace error, because you have named two things 1. you list `cart = []` and also 2. your function `def cart(): ...` with the same name. To fix it you need to rename either your function or your list. When you call `cart()` you're actually calling the list declared on the line directly above not the function at the top of the file.